# How can i solve "killed"?

Tags: python, out-of-memory, cluster-analysis, dask

I'm trying to plot clusters for my data which is stored in .data file  using the density peak clustering algorithm using [this code](https://github.com/yaox12/DensityPeakCluster/blob/master/plot.py)  but got `killed` as the file size is 8 Giga and my Ram is 32. how can I solve this problem, please?

the core problem in loading the whole file by this method

```
def density_and_distance(self, distance_file, dc = None):
    print("Begin")
    distance, num, max_dis, min_dis = load_data(distance_file)
    print("end")
    if dc == None:
        dc = auto_select_dc(distance, num, max_dis, min_dis)
    rho = local_density(distance, num, dc)
    delta, nearest_neighbor = min_distance(distance, num, max_dis, rho)
    
    self.distance = distance
    self.rho = rho
    self.delta = delta
    self.nearest_neighbor = nearest_neighbor
    self.num = num
    self.dc = dc

    return rho, delta
```

I got `Begin` word printed then got `killed` after some minutes

the file contains like

```
1 2 19.86
1 3 36.66
1 4 87.94
1 5 11.07
1 6 36.94
1 7 52.04
1 8 173.68
1 9 28.10
1 10 74.00
1 11 85.36
1 12 40.04
1 13 95.24
1 14 67.29
....
```

the method of reading the file is

```
def load_data(distance_file):
    distance = {}
    min_dis, max_dis = sys.float_info.max, 0.0
    num = 0
    with open(distance_file, 'r', encoding = 'utf-8') as infile:
        for line in infile:
            content = line.strip().split(' ')
            assert(len(content) == 3)
            idx1, idx2, dis = int(content[0]), int(content[1]), float(content[2])
            num = max(num, idx1, idx2)
            min_dis = min(min_dis, dis)
            max_dis = max(max_dis, dis)
            distance[(idx1, idx2)] = dis
            distance[(idx2, idx1)] = dis
        for i in range(1, num + 1):
            distance[(i, i)] = 0.0
        infile.close()
    
    return distance, num, max_dis, min_dis
```

**to be**

```
import dask.dataframe as dd 

def load_data(distance_file):
    distance = {}
    min_dis, max_dis = sys.float_info.max, 0.0
    num = 0
    #with open(distance_file, 'r', encoding = 'utf-8') as infile:
    df_dd = dd.read_csv("ex3.csv")
    print("df_dd",df_dd.head())
    #for line in df_dd:
    #content = df_dd.strip().split(' ')
    #print(content)
    idx1, idx2, dis = df_dd.partitions[0], df_dd.partitions[1], df_dd.partitions[2]
    print("df_dd.partitions[0]",df_dd.partitions[0])

    num = max(num, idx1, idx2)
    min_dis = min(min_dis, dis)
    max_dis = max(max_dis, dis)
    distance[(idx1, idx2)] = dis
    distance[(idx2, idx1)] = dis
    for i in range(1, num + 1):
         distance[(i, i)] = 0.0
    
    
    return distance, num, max_dis, min_dis
```

Comment: I've already changed the ram from  16 to be 32 and can't increase it more than 32 unfortunately but is there any solution to change the code to deal with this huge size of data

Comment: Unfortunately, to be on-topic here, the problem needs to be _reproducible_ -- complete enough we can run it ourselves to see the same problem.

Comment: ...that said... do you have swap defined? How much? At some point, you _do_ need to have enough memory (virtual or otherwise) to store the data in your working set.

Comment: Can you please include the actual error message? Also how big is your **distance_file** you are trying to load?

Comment: ...being able to work with data larger than memory efficiently is why people build things like databases with indexed datastores (so the indexes can be used to figure out what one needs to go to disk for). Eventually, you get to a place where you need to design your solution around the tools built to solve a problem if you want to not have that problem.

Comment: the file size is 8 Giga contains three columns for 30.000 points with the example i wrote it in the post now .. there is no error message, i just got killed in loading the file

Comment: "Killed" is what happen when you have Linux configured to allow overcommit and the OOM killer is on.

Comment: ...in that configuration (which is typical on modern systems), the operating system promises more memory than it can deliver, and then when it's called on those promises and can't fulfill them, kills whichever process looks like it's using the most memory (with some heuristics around the selection that are too complicated to go into right now).

Comment: You _can_ avoid that, by turning off overcommit, which will make an attempt to allocate more memory than you have fail immediately (such that the application gets informed of that failure, so you get a proper stack trace).

Comment: that said, bottom line is that "killed" is how out-of-memory errors typically present themselves on modern Linux unless you did some work to configure them to happen a different way.

Comment: excuse me how can i avoid loading the data in the memory .. i just need to use the data to plot the clusters , is there any way i can do it ?

Comment: You aren't showing us where any of your functions come from (there's no `import load_data from numpy` or such shown in the question), so how are we to know whether there are alternatives? _In general_, though, it depends on what the code needs to _do_ with that data; memory-mapped I/O is sometimes an option, but the tools you're using would have to be very deliberately written to work that way.

Comment: the method I mentioned takes parameter which is the distance_file that I passed it with.data extension

Comment: can someone help please ?

Comment: Not really, no. A question that nobody but you can reproduce (because nobody else has your hardware or dataset), where a proper solution probably involves completely rewriting your program to use an entirely different (more memory-efficient) algorithm (or even a different programming language that's amenable to tighter packing in RAM) is not something that fits well here.

Comment: i'm asking for a solution i will try it !! not need someone to try this code. if someone has good experience with the memory leak and know some methods that can work i will try it . if you don't know like me there is no problem, i hope i can find a solution or someone can help.

Comment: Now, what you might think about is figuring out what it would take to _not_ store your `distance` data in-memory at all, but to stream it right out to disk as you generate it. You might need to index or sort that data on-disk to make it useful, but there are techniques for doing that with data larger than RAM -- for example, breaking it down into chunks small enough to work with individually, and then merge-sorting those chunks together. But this involves a lot of figuring out what you need to do with your data, and designing a storage format / indexing mechanism that's amenable to that use.

Comment: (often one needs to index along more than one axis, and there one often gets into the space where using a preexisting database engine makes more sense than rolling your own).

Comment: the base problem is to find the maximum number and minimum number of the distance in this huge file and while loading it i got the problem

Comment: Right, I get that; but the thing is, while the base problem may be easy to describe in just a few words, the universe of things you might need to know to solve it is huge, almost unbounded. That's why the suggestions I'm giving you sound so abstract -- there are a bunch of concrete skills that you need to learn before you can even start to apply them, and those skills can't be taught inside the space of a Stack Overflow answer. (As it says in https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask, "if you can imagine a book that answers your question, you're asking too much" -- the typical approaches...

Comment: ...to solving this class of problem are very much textbook-worthy).

Comment: looking at your load_data function, one suggestion that come to mind is create a custom dictionary class to help you with your data storage, given that you store both d[(a,b)]=r and d[(b,a)]=r this custom class could be made to handle both at once by just storing only one of those, and just like that you reduce your memory consumption in half, you also store d[(a,a)]=0, this custom class can also be made to handle this case by always return 0 when checking for (a,a) and so you no longer need to store those and there it goes another huge chunk of memory...

Answer (score 1):

You are using Python native integers and floats: these alone take tens of bytes for each actual number in your data (28 bytes for an integer).

If you simply use Numpy or Pandas for that, your memory consumption might be slashed by a factor of 4 or more, without further adjustments.
Your lines average 10 bytes this early - at an 8GB file you should have less than 800 million registers - if you use 16bit integer numbers and 32 bit float that would mean that your data *might* fit in 10GB of memory. It is still a tight call, as the default pandas behavior is to copy everything on changes to a column. There are other options:

Since your code depends on indexing the rows as you've done there, you could just offload your data to an SQLite DB, and use in-sqlite indices instead of the dict you are using, as well as its min and max operators: this would offset memory usage, and sqlite would make its job with minimal fuss.

Another option would be to use "dask" instead of Pandas: it will take care of offloading data that would not fit in memory to disk.

TL;DR: the way your problem is arranged, maybe going to sqlite might be the way that would require less changes in what you have thought.

Comment: thanks a lot for answering but excuse me i make changes in the function can you see it please